# How can I run discord py 2.0 file on heroku

Tags: heroku, discord.py

I am getting error, while trying to run discord py 2.0 file on heroku:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement discord.py==2.0.0a4422+gdc50736b (from versions: 0.1.0, 0.2.0, 0.2.1,
0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.5.0, 0.5.1, 0.6.0, 0.6.1, 0.6.2, 0.6.3, 0.7.0, 0.8.0, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.9.2, 0.10.0, 0.11.0, 0.12.0, 0.13.0, 0.14.0, 0.14.1, 0.14.2, 0.14.3, 0.15.0, 0.15.1, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.16.2, 0.16.3, 0.16.4, 0.16.5, 0.16.6, 0.16.7, 0.16.8, 0.16.9, 0.16.10, 0.16.11, 0.16.12, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for discord.py==2.0.0a4422+gdc50736b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try

```
git+git://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
```

It doesn't work for me.

But when I try

```
git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
```

Which is written in `requirements.txt` The same as when I used "pip install", it can be deployed on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `discord.py==2.0.0a4422+gdc50736b`. Specify the Github link with the commit in your `requirements.txt` instead:

```
git+git://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@dc50736bfc3340d7b999d9f165808f8dcb8f1a60
```

However, I suggest instead of specifying that particular commit, you just specify the general repo so your discord library will be up-to-date with Rapptz's repo:

```
git+git://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
```

**Reference:**

- [Git-backed distributions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip#git-backed-distributions)